# CLR Stored Procedure referencing Websphere-MQ .dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, ibm-mq, clrstoredprocedure

I'm trying to write a CLR Store Procedure inside a Visual Studio 2010 C# SQL CLR Database Project. Unfortunately I have a class created that needs a reference to an external Webshpere MQ assembly, which SQL Projects are not able to do. I tried to create a separate class library within the project that did contain the necessary reference, however when I tried to add the reference to THIS project I was told that "SQL Server projects can only reference other SQL Server Projects." Can anyone help me with a work-around?

Comment: What happens when you try to add the assembly to the project directly?

Comment: I created one sample SQL CLR Database Project. Add Reference dialog does now show WebSphere MQ assemblies. And there isn't a browse button to pick amqmdnet assembly. I get the same error as NealR when I try to add a project that has reference to MQ. The error is not because of a reference to MQ assemblies. It's simply that one can only add SQL Server project as a reference and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not technically possible. An SQL project made with Visual Studio 2010 cannot reference any outside assemblies, or any other Visual Studio projects other than SQL projects.